# Can I define new attributes in XMP for PDF?

Tags: pdf, xmp

I know there are some attributes in XMP for PDF files such as:

```xml
     <xap:ModifyDate>2009-12-10T09:54:47-05:00</xap:ModifyDate>
     <xap:CreateDate>2009-12-10T09:42:54-05:00</xap:CreateDate>
     <xap:MetadataDate>2009-12-10T09:54:47-05:00</xap:MetadataDate>
     <xap:CreatorTool>Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0.4)</xap:CreatorTool>
```

But I want to define custom attributes for example:

```xml
     <xap:ViewTitle>2009-12-10T09:54:47-05:00</xap:ViewTitle>
     <xap:GUID>2009-12-10T09:42:54-05:00</xap:GUID>
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

According to XMP Specification

> New properties may be added to existing namespaces without “breaking”
>   applications.
>
> The definitions of properties in existing namespaces should always
>   remain the same; otherwise, applications may produce incorrect
>   behavior. If it is necessary to change the meaning of a property, a
>   new property should be created (and the old one declared as
>   deprecated).

And you can create new custom schemas. Probably it's a better approach than extending existing schema.

More information can be found in *Extensibility of Schemas* in XMP Specification.

Comment: Can The PDF files be sorted according to XMP attributes? for example grouping files according to CreateDate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XMP bridge libraryto edit XMP. Marijan Tompa gave great insights on its blog : 
http://indisnip.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/storing-custom-data-into-indesign-file-xmp/